# centering icon according to div and putting space between divs

Tags: html, css

I am kinda new to web design issues (html, css etc) and trying to make something like this:
[image]

I don't know how to make that fa-envelope-o icon centered both horizontally and vertically. I tried something like this:

```
#envelopeDiv{
    background-color: red;
    width:62px;
    height:42px;
    line-height:42px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

#disableAllDiv .big-icon{
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: inherit;
}

#disableAllDiv{
    background-color: #4caf50;
}

#disableAllButton{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

It didn't give me the correct result. Can anyone provide sample code or more professional approach? **Even "how to research" would be very useful.**

Comment: Please include the HTML, as well. Also, a working demo (with images or placeholders) would be helpful (e.g., jsfiddle.net).

Comment: But for a general centering solution (both vertical and horizontal), [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the most modern technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B, thank you. I will try flexbox and return shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael_B said in his comment above, `flexbox` is probably the most modern way to go about this.

The horizontal centering is easily done with `margin: auto`, but the `vertical-align` is more difficult, so I'll post a non-CSS approach.

However, I (with my weird own ways) like to go about this straightforwardly with JS (and jQuery): center it with absolute positioning by setting its `left` and `top` to half the `width` and `height` (respectively) of the container minus half the `width` and `height` of the image, dynamically.

```js
$("img").css({
  "top": $("div").height() / 2 - $("img").height() / 2,
  "left": $("div").width() / 2 - $("img").width() / 2,
 "position": "absolute"
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #aaf;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/envelope-with-letter-clipart-envelope-md.png" />
</div>
```

See a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/crkxh5jg/) on JSFiddle.net.

---

**EDIT**

Now that I think about it, if you know what the height and width of your container and image is going to be, then this will be easy by just setting a certain padding to the container.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/crkxh5jg/1/) on JSFiddle.net.